# Simple Implementation of BiSS C interface for a position encoder

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, control, feedback, encoder

The BiSS C DB3 protocol interface for Absolute encoder is an Open Source and Free Communication protocol hardware compatible with SSI interface. It is used widely in absolute position encoders. However, searching for sample codes and implementations yields zero results. Most BiSS master are Closed source FPGA based or ASIC like (ICHAUS.de) or some (TI.com) microprocessors.

I want to replace an SSI encoder with BiSS in my DIY CNC machine, because it contains CRC and i want some kind of checksum to ensure the data read is correct. **It is a point to point connection.** I am only interested in reading the position. Not all the intelligent functions.

*So my 2-part Question :*

**1- Can i get away with simple implementation (read position only) on the same 8-bit micro-controller that i am using now for SSI that is doing other staff . Or it is mandatory to set certain functions and registers for the device to work.**

**2- If I want to go the extra mile and implement a full BiSS master on a dedicated 8-bit Micro, is it a one man job ? too complex ? Any advice in this regard.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You could use a development kit to program the necessary parameters then use read only mode on the same microcontroller .

2- offcourse , IChaus has an implementation written for PIC16F , you have to be licensee to get it for free.