# Implementing line propagation delay compensation for BiSS master in software

Tags: microcontroller, spi, control, encoder

Following up on a question I asked some time ago: [Simple Implementation of BiSS C interface for a position encoder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301868/simple-implementation-of-biss-c-interface-for-a-position-encoder). I have implemented a simple BiSS master (point to point) to communicate with an encoder. At frequencies below 2 MHz and short cable length, the software is working perfectly using SPI module on PIC microcontroller.

However I tried high speed (3 to 10 MHz) and a 10 m cable, which should work. I stumbled across a propagation delay issue. It appears the protocol needs an implementation of cycle by cycle delay compensation.

[image: A snippet from TI TIDU410 showing the problem]

I tried an approach in which I depend on the start sequence (ACK and Start bit) and I shift the result by 1 or 2 or 3 bits depending on how many clocks was the start bit late. But it does not work all the time, the problem seems to be that the data might be shifted by any fraction of the clock (ex.: 1/8, 1/4, 1, 1.5) so MISO is not decoding at the right time all the time.

**Does anyone have thoughts on proper way to implement such function in microcontroller? (I can add a couple of discrete componets and logic gates if necessary) but not an FPGA.**

*EDIT ( Screen shot from oscilloscope ) using standard SPI functions *
[image]

Screen shot from oscilloscope when directly puting data in SPI buffer without wait or any function whatsoever 
[image]

Screen shot when using Buffered mode , 2 spi writes . Note the signal is clean , but the oscilloscope probe and ground pin was not idle when taking the photo..
[image]

Comment: what's your mcu clock speed?

Comment: @BeB00 , i am running at 60MIPS , 16.67ns is the instruction time ( incase you are wondering about bit banging )

Comment: well you can't change the way the SPI peripheral works, so bit banging is pretty much the only thing you can do unless you want to get an external chip. For 10MHz, 80 MIPS would be more comfortable, but 60 might work

Comment: @BeB00 , is there any improved way of bit banging , better than port Read and LAT write , to improved noise/glitch immunity ( something like super sampling , or multiple reads of the same bit ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, generally no. There are no special peripherals for reading/writing pins on a typical pic microcontroller.

Comment: Which PIC processor do you use?

Comment: @Dorian , DSPIC33EP ( MU series ) currently for this project , other PICs i have access to PIC32MK and PIC32MZ

Comment: I see, whas speed is used in the graph?

Comment: Can you post the code used to read the SPI active for this graph?

Comment: @ElectronS do you actually realize what the limitation is with a slave responding to the master at high speeds and with significant line lengths?

Comment: @Andyaka , yes i realize , but this Protocol works at this speed and this length for sure ( with line delay compensation ). TI has a development board for this thing (www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu794a/tidu794a.pdf)  , but they use a built in module in their microcontoller ( a slightly modified SPI module ) with all these functions included , but i cannot afford this high end processor , neither the custom ASIC by IC-haus company . and i want to explore the limitations of my hardware and software . sorry for the lengthy comment :)

Comment: Can you implement master to slave then, for the slave response, swap roles so that the original master takes the clock from the new master (the former slave). Is there enough intelligence at the slave end to implement this?

Comment: Uh , i don't know if Andy meant this but answer hit me like a storm. Use SPI in slave mode and use a different pin (using output compare or something) to generate the clock signal for both PIC and BISS slave.  That way the clock signal will be steady without any breaks. If you somehow gate the clock that goes to the PIC  you might compensate the delay as stated in the BISS protocol

Comment: @Dorian , nice idea , i makes sense . only the last part about gating the clock i donot understand . and by the way i am using 10mhz clock oscillator to OSCIN Pin ( use PLL to make 120mhz to get the 60MIPS )

Comment: To start later than BISS clock.

Comment: Don't use OSCIN or OSCOUT pins, you can mess your system clock , see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the delay is somehow constant or with small jitter and the signal gets to SPI in good shape.

Updated after OP's observations that SPI communication is not back to back as I assumed so some bits are lost between frames.

**Update after Andy's hint, the right solution is to use both BISS sensor and PIC SPI in slave mode and generate two clocks either externally gated by a PIC output or internally using timer output compare, or other way**

With both clocks idle in "1" start DMA for SPI receive, start BISS interface clock, pool the ACK bit then start PIC SPI clock. Sampling in the middle will ensure enough hazard margin. The data will be aligned in words, no shifting is needed. The second DMA for dummy transmitting is no more needed.

You can find in the [Microchip document about output compare module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61111E.pdf#G1.883808) page 9 how to use the output compare module to generate a clock starting from high level.  The speed can be up to 1/8 system clock.

It might be possible depending on the PIC capabilities that the SPI clock pin (input because we use SPI in slave mode) to be driven by using PPS without using another pin and external hardwired connection.

In this case, using software shifting as below, the board can be used without any hardware modification.

**Using OP's solution to shift delayed data:**

To get reliable readings first thing to do is to change the Data Input Sample Phase bit SMPx to sample the data at the end instead of the middle as i suppose it is. Or in the middle if it is on the end now

[image]

(The image has a mistake, the first edge of the "sample at the end" is not an active reading edge.)

**It would be better to know by software which sample edge is better to use.**

The description is made for SPI slave shifting data on the first falling edge, for the BISS interface that shift ACK on the second rising edge you can make the necessary corrections adding 0.5 Tckh or 1.5 Tckh to the delay.

Put your SPI clock on the highest usable value Ckh (Tckh period), count the bits until ACK arrives, change Data Input Sample Phase bit SMPx send another message and count the bits again.

That will give you a half clock period approximation of the delay. Use that to choose the sampling point for the clock you actually use Ck (Tck period). If the speed you use it's at most half then it's enough.

If the readings have the same number of "1" until ACK then the delay is between(N_ones) x Tckh and (N_ones + 1/2) x Tckk

If the end reading has one more "1" than the delay is between (N_ones + 1/2) x Tck and N_ones+1 x Tck

Back to the clock you actually will use. If a multiply of the clock period Tck touches the delay area then use the sample at the middle, if not than use sample at the end. If you used Ckh more than double then use the sampling time that is most far from the delay area.

Update, corrected the inverted representation of the signal in the text and add some graphic for better understanding

**Same number of ones using fast clock, delay between 5 and 5.5 Tckh:**

[image]

**Sampling in the middle using fast clock reads an additional "1". Delay between 5.5 and 6 Tckh.** (*6 "1" for sampling at the middle not 5 as is in the image*)

[image]

**Using SPI clock, use sampling edge most far from delay area.** 
[image]

The diagrams were made using [WaveDorm online editor](https://wavedrom.com/)

Comment: regarding the first sentence , the signal get to SPI in very good shape ( i confirm with Oscillscope with short GND lead ) . the Delay should be constant for a specific configuration ( speed and length ) .

Comment: what you presented is brilliant , since i am currently sampling at the falling edge , i will try changing that at the speed where it is not working and see the results , in that case , i will make a sort of calibration function that will choose the sampling polarity based on some read cycles . i will get back when i can confirm the result , thanks :)

Comment: After an hour of Testing , the solution you proposed worked partially ( some bits are still mistaken ) following those error i found the problem , it is in the Pause between words sent . Since i am using 16-bit archituture , and using SPI in 16bit mode ( word not byte ) and i am sending/Receiving 2 words, there is a pause of about 3 clocks between the 2 words . This delay is causing a problem with the delay compensation algorithm , NOW it appears i have figure out if i can eliminate this delay or i have to use PIC32 ( 32bit spi ) , do you have any thought ?

Comment: I have added an screen shot to question ...

Comment: I've noticed that to, I think we all assumed that the bytes are sent back to back since you were talking about shifting bytes. That's why I was asking about the code, to see if it can be improved for back to back communication

Comment: @ElectronS , using buffered (enhanced) SPI still keeps the break between bytes?

Comment: sadly DSPIC33/PIC24 doesnot support enhanced buffer mode , FRM ( SPI ) page 6 , note 1

Comment: I guess thats because it supports DMA , i will try DMA now , hopefully it will eliminate the delay between Sent WORDs

Comment: @ElectronS Might not  work with DMA because I see it uses SPI transfer done and I suppose it's related with  SPI data ready that has half clock delay. You might need to write two words in the TX buffer before starting the TX DMA to have the buffer always full

Comment: you are right it didnot, next test will be on PIC32 , just to prove the concept . in all cases thanks a lot for the well written and improved answer :) you deserve more than a silly bounty , i am keeping it open just to allow others to contribute ( only 95 views of the question so far )

Comment: by the way how did you draw these diagrams of clock ?

Comment: There is an online tool, don't have-it handy now. You're right, I should put a reference to it at least.  There are more things you can try but now I'm a bit busy, Ill come back later.

Comment: @ElectronS Don't use SPI functions, just write the SPI TX register twice and see what happens. You still have the break?

Comment: bravo again , written 2 times in a row ,it doesnot send another word , since it is still sending , but when i write to spi tx 5 times in a row ( SPI1BUF = 0xFFFF ) , it worked !! the delay is reduced from 750ns to 300ns approximatly ( see the new screen shot) . but it was not completely eliminated

Comment: also the constant writing to the SP1BUF makes reading the of the incoming data impossible ( since it is the same register ) , my original function did the following : SP1BUF = dummy , while (!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF) , temp1 = SPI1BUF . then repeat those 3 lines , after that temp3 =  temp1<<16 + temp2 .

Comment: Still something is not right, I don't think that the 5 time writing has to do something with that , rather the timing. The fifth was at a better moment. When writing two words two words must be sent since one goes right in the shift register and one is buffered. I have a PIC24FJ  available, it has the same SPI unit I will make a test on Monday. Your question is also very challenging and in my area of intrest.

Comment: you were right , i had the buffer disabled , now when i enable it , 2 time writing to SPI1BUF works , the delay is now 150ns about 1 cycle ( i think this is intentional ) , i added another photo , showing a potential problem , since 1 data bit is in the zone where no clock edge is present , hence it will not be decoded

Comment: @ElectronS Try to change the clock mode to. Maybe some modes don't have the delay?

Comment: i have spent 7 hours today working with the brilliant method you proposed after andy's Hint , however no success. I generated 10Mhz clock (using output compare ) and tied it to SPI clock and put the SPI module in Slave , however no matter how hard i tried , i am only receiving the first word . I looks like the module needs the Break ( or small pause between the sent words ) i verified this using the Buffer mode , and checking the SPI status register , i donot know if posting a snippet of the code would help , thanks anyway for the effort

Comment: @ElectronS I will try myself tomorrow. Have you tried using 8 bit mode?

Comment: no i didnot try the 8 bit mode , i will continue testing , the problem is this is the first time i use the slave mode and there is some important details missing from the FRM . like (should you load dummy data to be sent , like when using Master mode) ... yes try it your self and tell me what happens

Comment: @ElectronS I think I was wrong, maybe not feeding the SPI TX register raise an error that prevents further readings. Try first to feed two words then pool the SPI transfer complete for further writes. 100% a break between  words is not needed, after all it's a slave.

Comment: Finally , i am happy to announce that it worked !!!! at full speed , the SPI slave problem was ( as i have read on Microchip forum ) could get stuck and work unreliably if it receives a clock with the SPIbuffer ( in enhanced mode ) empty , I was putting chars in the buffer , but not after initialization . So adding SPI1BUF= 0x Dummy , after OpenSPI(function) . made it work :)

Comment: Another problem that you might face and i have , is if you generate more clocks than required lets say 40 , this will the data received be wrong ( 2 correct words and 1 half word ) , the nextime data will arrive it will be aligend to the old half word of garbage . So after each operation i restart the SPI , to flush the RX FIFO buffer of excess data.

Comment: @ElectronS Great news !! So my morning guess was good.  I was struggling with that to right now. You might put your findings in your question for others that might needed. Not the source code but at least some guidance.

Comment: I knew that SPI slave must have data in SPIbuf , and i was doing that before generating the Clock ( Output compare ) in the BISS read function. however the first time the clock is generated ( in OC initalize ) at that moment there is characters in the buffer , thats why i missed the point , So it was really tricky to know the problem. I will post an answer containing The tips and tricks if that would help . but really thank you for the patience and good help i needed to interact and challenge my self with another fellow engineer , could not have done it without YOU :))

Comment: Anytime, it was something to learn for me to.